# Enable cross-site tracking for iOS network requests

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I would like to **enable** cross-site tracking for one of my iOS network requests - I can't find anything on which configuration setting would provide that option. I am using a shared `URLSession` and for every request I create a separate `URLSessionDataTask`.

Is there anything in the public APIs that I can use to enable cross-site tracking?

On desktop Safari, as a user, I can uncheck `Prevent cross-site tracking`.

[image]

I would like to know how to achieve the same on iOS, as a developer.